# Contextual CSS reset after YUI Normalize.css

Tags: css

I am building a widget. The widget will be deployed in other websites. I need to ensure that the styling of the widget is consistent across all websites. When deployed it will exist as follows

```
<div id="myWidget>Some content and child divs, etc.</div>
```

I understand that to remove all styles set by the host website the css is

```
#myWidget * { all: initial; }
```

This isn't an ideal solution as you start from barebones and need to apply styling for every element on top of that. My question is, if I want to use css frameworks e.g. https://getbootstrap.com or https://purecss.io how do I make them contextual and only apply to the elements contained within the `#myWidget` div - i.e. not affect elements outside of the widget?

https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssnormalize/ used to do this, but unfortunately is no longer supported (as of 2014) and I'm finding that some items need to be manually reset e.g. box-shadow.

Comment: Have a look here: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have had a look at normalize.css however if I were to include that in the widget it would overwrite all styles in the page, rather than those within my widget alone.